# Running Python script from anywhere on windows platform

Tags: python, windows

I am keeping a folder inside my windows machine(my_codes) where I keep all my codes. I have added this folder path to my path env variable inside windows path.

Now when I call the script from somewhere I am not able to pass the argument correctly.

```
(base) C:\Users\abc>test.py abc.csv
print_test
C:\Users\abc\my_codes\test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\my_codes\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The python code is as below. I have saved it as test.py inside C:\Users\abc\my_codes

```
import sys      
print('print_test')
print(sys.argv[0])
print(sys.argv[1])
```

This works perfectly inside linux but unable to get it work in windows so far.

This works inside windows too if I call it this way.

```
(base) C:\Users\abc>python my_codes/test.py abc.csv
print_test
my_codes/test.py
abc.csv
```

However I do not want to call by specifying the full path each time to the python file.

Comment: can you try add `#!C:/thefullpathtoyourpythoninstall.python.exe`? i think this relates to how cmd interpretes `test.py abc.csv` maybe it sees two possible seprate commands and tries to execute one by one.

Comment: I added this line in test.py and still same error.
#!C:\Users\abc\Miniconda3\python.exe

Answer (score 0):

I created a function in powershell as below:-

```
function test {
     python C:\Users\abc\my_codes\test.py $args
}

(base) C:\Users\abc>test abc.csv
print_test
my_codes/test.py
abc.csv
```

and I am able to call test abc.csv. It serves my purpose but I would have loved to get it done in more proper way.

Comment: this is just a walkaround.

Comment: @LeiYang Agree I also don't like it.

Comment: i have tried myself. when i type the filename it invokes my ide gui! so it must depend on the system configuration(what application is associated with .py).

Comment: @LeiYang change default open as from your ide to python.exe for the file. In that way it will not open your ide.

Comment: Windows has a configuration that tells it Python.exe should be used to run .py files.  Part of that configuration is also what parameters should be passed to the command.

Comment: Here's a starting point: [Verbs and File Associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-verbs).